# Core Animation bad access on device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-animation, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to do a frame by frame animation with CAlayers. I'm doing this with this tutorial http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/ but everything works with disable ARC, when I'm try to rewrite code with ARC, it's works on simulator perfectly but on device I got a bad access memory.

Layer Class interface

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface MCSpriteLayer : CALayer {
    unsigned int sampleIndex;
}

// SampleIndex needs to be > 0
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) unsigned int sampleIndex; 

// For use with sample rects set by the delegate
+ (id)layerWithImage:(CGImageRef)img;
- (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img;

// If all samples are the same size 
+ (id)layerWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size;
- (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size;

// Use this method instead of sprite.sampleIndex to obtain the index currently displayed on screen
- (unsigned int)currentSampleIndex; 


@end
```

Layer Class implementation

```
@implementation MCSpriteLayer

@synthesize sampleIndex;

- (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.contents = (__bridge id)img;
        sampleIndex = 1;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (id)layerWithImage:(CGImageRef)img;
{
    MCSpriteLayer *layer = [(MCSpriteLayer*)[self alloc] initWithImage:img];
    return layer ;
}


- (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size;
{
    self = [self initWithImage:img];  // IN THIS LINE IS BAD ACCESS
    if (self != nil)
    {
        CGSize sampleSizeNormalized = CGSizeMake(size.width/CGImageGetWidth(img), size.height/CGImageGetHeight(img));
        self.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, size.width, size.height );
        self.contentsRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, sampleSizeNormalized.width, sampleSizeNormalized.height );
    }

    return self;
}


+ (id)layerWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size;
{
    MCSpriteLayer *layer = [[self alloc] initWithImage:img sampleSize:size];
    return layer;
}


+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key;
{
    return [key isEqualToString:@"sampleIndex"];
}

// contentsRect or bounds changes are not animated
+ (id < CAAction >)defaultActionForKey:(NSString *)aKey;
{
    if ([aKey isEqualToString:@"contentsRect"] || [aKey isEqualToString:@"bounds"])
        return (id < CAAction >)[NSNull null];

    return [super defaultActionForKey:aKey];
}


- (unsigned int)currentSampleIndex;
{
    return ((MCSpriteLayer*)[self presentationLayer]).sampleIndex;
}


// Implement displayLayer: on the delegate to override how sample rectangles are calculated; remember to use currentSampleIndex, ignore sampleIndex == 0, and set the layer's bounds
- (void)display;
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLayer:)])
    {
        [self.delegate displayLayer:self];
        return;
    }

    unsigned int currentSampleIndex = [self currentSampleIndex];
    if (!currentSampleIndex)
        return;

    CGSize sampleSize = self.contentsRect.size;
    self.contentsRect = CGRectMake(
        ((currentSampleIndex - 1) % (int)(1/sampleSize.width)) * sampleSize.width, 
        ((currentSampleIndex - 1) / (int)(1/sampleSize.width)) * sampleSize.height, 
        sampleSize.width, sampleSize.height
    );
}


@end
```

I create the layer on viewDidAppear and start animate by clicking on button, but after init I got a bad access error

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mama_default.png" ofType:nil];
    CGImageRef richterImg = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path].CGImage;
    CGSize fixedSize = animacja.frame.size;
    NSLog(@"wid: %f, heigh: %f", animacja.frame.size.width, animacja.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f", animacja.frame.size.width);

    richter = [MCSpriteLayer layerWithImage:richterImg sampleSize:fixedSize];
    animacja.hidden = 1;
    richter.position = animacja.center;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:richter];
}

-(IBAction)animacja:(id)sender
{
    if ([richter animationForKey:@"sampleIndex"])
    {NSLog(@"jest");
    }
    if (! [richter animationForKey:@"sampleIndex"])
    {
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"sampleIndex"];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:22];
    anim.duration = 4;
    anim.repeatCount = 1;

    [richter addAnimation:anim forKey:@"sampleIndex"];
    }

}
```

Have you got any idea how to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are you getting the bad access? In what method on what line? Does the manual reference counting code work on the device?

Comment: BAD ACCES is when I try to init layer:    
 - (id)initWithImage:(CGImageRef)img sampleSize:(CGSize)size;
    {
        self = [self initWithImage:img];  // <--- IN THIS LINE IS BAD ACCESS

When I compile every class without arc with code from mystery coconut it work on device

Comment: A few remarks, that didn’t belong in my answer: 1. Unless there’s a very compelling reason, don’t use `+[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`! Use `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` instead (see the excellent documentation for an explanation). 2. It’s good practice to have only **one** designated initializer, which **all** other initializers call — the one that takes the most parameters. In your case, that would be `-[MCSpriteLayer initWithImage:sampleSize:]`. 3. There’s no compelling reason that said method expects a `CGImageRef` instead of a `UIImage`, so don’t do that — otherwise, rename the method.

Comment: Is your `richter` property declared as `@property (nonatomic, strong) MCSpriteLayer *richter;` in your view controller header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your crash comes from a dangling `CGImageRef`.

You can fix it by e.g. changing the line

```
richter = [MCSpriteLayer layerWithImage:richterImg sampleSize:fixedSize];
```

to

```
richter = [MCSpriteLayer layerWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mama_default"] CGImage] sampleSize:fixedSize];
```

or a number of equivalent options.

### Explanation

To explain what’s going on, I’ll slightly modify, and annotate your implementation of `viewWillAppear:`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // 1
    UIImage *richterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mama_default"];
    // 2
    CGImageRef backingImage = richterImage.CGImage;
    CGSize fixedSize = animacja.frame.size;

    // 3
    richter = [MCSpriteLayer layerWithImage:backingImage sampleSize:fixedSize];
    animacja.hidden = 1;
    richter.position = animacja.center;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:richter];
}
```

Let‘s go through the comments:

1. You ask the `UIImage` class for an image, and it answers by returning a *non-owning* reference.
2. You ask that image for its primitive backing-store, (the `CGImage`) and it answers by returning a *non-owning* reference to the memory of that store. Note, that this is **not** an Objective-C object!
3. You use the *non-owning* reference to that backing store as the argument for creating your sprite layer.

Under manual reference counting, the object from step 1 lives in the nearest enclosing autorelease pool. Because you don’t see one anywhere near your code, *that object is **implicitly** guaranteed to outlive the scope of your implementation of `viewDidAppear:`*.

Under ARC, that is not the case:
Because the object returned in step 1 is never referenced after step 2, that object **may go away** any line after step two, which is the last reference to it. And because the backing-store is **not** an Objective-C object, referencing it any time later without having *explicitly* claimed interest (through `CGImageRetain`, e.g.) in it, it becomes invalid **as soon as the `UIImage` becomes invalid**.

Because under ARC the compiler inserts calls to special functions that are *functionally equivalent* to the methods `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` but *constant*, it can optimize some of the redundant retain/(auto-)release pairs away, thus minimizing messaging overhead, and the lifetime of certain objects.

How *aggressively* it optimizes those, however, is an implementation detail, and depends on a number of parameters. So when you call `layerWithImage:sampleSize:`, (which lays claim to the CGImageRef in `self.contents = (__bridge id)img;`) the first parameter you pass in *may* or *may not* be a pointer to invalid memory, based on how aggressively the compiler optimized your code.